# TempData not working with dropzone's javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropzone.js

How do I get the javascript function on a dropzone.on(success) to use tempdata.

I need to return a value from the controller back to the success call.

I think this might just be a javascript question, but im really not sure.

Here is the code.

```
 submitButton.addEventListener("click",
                function() {

                    //tell Dropzone to process all queued files
                    myDropzone.processQueue();

                    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete",
                        function() {
                            this.removeAllFiles();

                            var orderNumber = '@(TempData["OrderNumber"])';

                            var url = "@Url.Action("OrderConfirmation", "Upload")" + '?orderNumber= ' + orderNumber;
                            window.location.replace(url);

                        });
                });
```

Comment: are you getting an error or empty data?

Comment: While debugging, does the TempData hold a value or empty?

Comment: Yes. The value empty.

Comment: So you need to check your server side code first and make sure the TempData has value.